# Regex match digits before 2 characters, using OR google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I'm using `REGEXEXTRACT` in Google Sheets which uses the RE2 RegEx.

I want to get digits in a string that occur either before the character `P` or before the characters `MC`.

here is what i have so far: `(\.?\d*).?MC` this works if my text is something like "`FM.3 MC1`". In Google Sheets it is like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\.?\d*).?MC")
```

This works for getting digits before `MC`, I want to add OR `P` like this:

```
(\.?\d*).?MC|P
```

This returns `.3` if my text is "`FM.3 MC1`", but is blank if my text is "`FM.3 MC1 P2`" or "`FM.3 P1`" and returns `#N/A` if my text is "`FM.3`".

Also if my regex is `(\.?\d*).?P|MC` , then it returns `.3` if my text is "`FM.3 P1`" is blank if my text is "`FM.3 MC P1`"

I'm not sure if this is RegEx, or if Google Sheets are being weird.

I'm looking for tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\.?\d*)\W?(?:MC|P)
```

I replaced `.?` (=any 1 or 0 chars) with `\W` as I think there can only be a non-word char between the number and the letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKtT3B/1).

**Details**

- `(\.?\d*)` - Group 1 (what `REGEXEXTRACT` returns): an optional `.` followed with 0 or more digits (change to `(\.?\d+)` to match 1 or more digits)
- `\W?` - an optional non-word char
- `(?:MC|P)` - a non-capturing group (thus, it is not returned with `REGEXEXTRACT`) either an `MC` substring or a `P` char.

Comment: thanks, also thanks for regex101 , I was not aware of that tool

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED (I can't be bothered to construct a sensible data sample from the format you have chosen):

```
=join("",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.?\d*).?MC|(.?\d*).P"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To group the two ending conditions, you need to wrap them in parentheses.

```js
var input = [
  "FM.3 MC1",
  "FM.3 MC1 P2",
  "FM.3",
  "FM.3 P2"
];
var patterns = [
  /(.?\d*).?MC|P/g,
  /(.?\d*).?(MC|P)/g
];
for (let p = 0; p < patterns.length; ++p) {
  console.log("Using pattern '" + String(patterns[p]) + "':");
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    console.log("\tFrom '" + input[i] + "', found " + (input[i].match(patterns[p]) || "(no matches)"));
  }
}
```

You can get a live look at your regex matches with a tool like regextester or regex101, among others.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it didn't quite work for me in google sheets

Answer (score 0):

if anyone interested in a catch all formula for any scenario/formatting with 'h' and 'm', in case your input is a mix of single/double digits and without/without minutes or hours ie:

1h
01h
1h 2m
01h 2m
01h 02m
1h 02m
02m
2m

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "m"), REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(\d{1,2})h \d{1,2}m") + REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^\d{1,2}h (\d{1,2})m")/60, SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h","",)
```